# Can't hear my vocals

Tags: vocals, problems

I unplugged my mic from the Mbox 2 temporarily and when I plugged it back in I was unable to hear my vocals.  I know they are recording because I can see the track but it is silent when i play it back.  I'm using pro tools 8.05 LE using macbook with snow leopard.  I know the fader levels are ok + the track isn't on mute.  Someone please help me!

Comment: Is input only monitoring turned off?

Comment: @Andy - does LE even have input monitoring? i thought it didn't

Comment: Yes LE does have input only monitoring

Comment: Option K toggles between "input only monitoring" and "Auto input monitoring" on PTLE.   This question is most likely more of a DUC, Digi forum question then a SSD question.  

Comment: @Iain but he's using PT 8 LE.

Comment: Azimuth answered that one. I was thinking about the Input Monitoring button in the TDM systems. And yes, this is a question for DUC.

Comment: Input only monitoring is an option on my version of PT 8 LE.

Comment: @Shaun the LE system doesn't have the I button on the channel strip but you can still toggle it on and off if the recording track is record armed - the two dots next to the timecode data at the top of the edit window shows this.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly either your outputs are wrong or your I/O has been changed.

Are you sending it to the correct outputs? Generally Outputs 1 & 2 should be your default.

Have you recently changed your I/O settings?

Answer (score 1):

There's a knob on the mBox 2 labelled "Mix". If you turn it in one direction, you'll only hear whatever's plugged into your inputs (mics, etc.). If you turn it in the other direction, you'll hear your Pro Tools outputs. I can never remember which direction is which, but it's easy enough to check.

Comment: Left is for source (Mic) and right is for computer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone who happens to google this question and come here like I did, look at your inserts. That's to the left of i/o and to the right of instruments (if your newer like me, it where it probably says Xpand!2). You're gonna want to right click that and click on bypass. That fixed it right up for me!